# Equal heights of columns in a row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiple-columns

I'm trying to set the columns in my row to have equal heights and it seems that this script is not working. It is making my columns equal BUT setting the heights to 0px.

**JS**

```
var EqualColumnHeight = {
  equalizeColumnHeights: function() {
    if ($( window ).width() > 720) {
      //$('.row .equal-height').equalHeights();
      $('.equals .equal-height').each( function () {
        $(this).css('height', $(this).parent().height()+'px');
      });
    } else {
      $('.equals .equal-height').each(function() {
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', '40px');
      });
    }
  }
};

$(window).load(function () {
  EqualColumnHeight.equalizeColumnHeights();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.dark-box {
  background: rgba(9,31,38,.8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row equals">
  <div class="five columns dark-box equal-height">
    <h2>Proin commodo metus id aliquam egestas</h2>
    <p>Donec lobortis elit nunc, vitae tristique odio dictum in. Curabitur risus dui, porta non malesuada id, dapibus et ex. Suspendisse euismod nec risus ac vehicula. Cras lobortis tellus id maximus laoreet. Sed sit amet aliquam ex, ut malesuada justo. Aliquam id lacus at leo faucibus interdum vel nec urna.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="five columns dark-box equal-height">
    <h2>Ut sed urna in elit consectetur laoreet</h2>
    <p>Etiam finibus dapibus urna, in eleifend lorem molestie a. Nulla tincidunt quis lectus sit amet tincidunt. Nunc vehicula feugiat leo, at pretium erat lacinia posuere. Mauris posuere odio non urna suscipit, vel imperdiet dolor fermentum. Etiam finibus scelerisque molestie. Aenean bibendum est lacus, ac sollicitudin est cursus ut. Nam sed ante vel nulla mollis tincidunt. Phasellus nec massa lacinia, accumsan velit sit amet, cursus mauris. Pellentesque ligula nulla, elementum ac risus in, volutpat efficitur odio. Nullam ut arcu venenatis, molestie mauris sit amet, egestas metus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are your columns visible? jQuery can't compute the height of an element that either isn't attached to the DOM or has `display: none`

Comment: @Wex they are visible. I'll add the CSS into the code above

Comment: *It is making my columns equal BUT setting the heights to 0px.* No it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a jsFiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/xpdg5ov2/5/

I was getting an error when doing `$(window).load` I had to change it to `$(document).ready`

I also noticed that the parent height changed through each loop

EDIT: in that one, the divs were indeed the same height, but the parent height changed after it changed the children. so I just made it vertically align to the top:
http://jsfiddle.net/xpdg5ov2/5/

Also notice, your window has to be over 720 pixels. due to your code. here is a jsfiddle without the window limit http://jsfiddle.net/xpdg5ov2/6/

FULL code just incase jsfiddle doesnt work for you:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var parentHeight = $('.equals .equal-height').parent().height();
      $('.equals .equal-height').each( function () {
        $(this).css('height', parentHeight+'px');
      });
});
```

CSS:

```
.dark-box {
    background: rgba(9, 31, 38, .8);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 45%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Comment: @JoshuaPack I'm not seeing that your columns in your fiddle are same height either. Am I missing something? I did try your fix in my code and now it's not setting the height to 0 but also the columns are not same height

Comment: You are right @tjoenz I thought it was loading correctly, I will look into it real quick

Comment: @JoshuaPack that one seems to just line the boxes to the bottom and the colored background isn't equal heights

Comment: @tjoenz the div's are equal height, but it looks like the parent changes in size after it changes the heights, so i had to make them go up http://jsfiddle.net/xpdg5ov2/5/ using css `vertical-align: text-top;`

Comment: Now you got it. Note to OP: I'd use `height()` rather than `css()` for simplicity.